# Adding more than one class

Tags: html, css

Is it bad thing if I add more than one class for one object. Let's say:

`<a href="#" class="paren" class="defaul">text</a>`

Don't ask me why, I just need it.

Thanks.

Comment: No it's not a bad thing. I use it quite often. It's useful to separate different concerns into different classes. Your syntax is wrong though.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, it's a perfectly reasonable question.  Upvoted to balance it out.

Comment: Bear in mind that you could run into problems with IE6 if you try to style that element using both classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939105/whats-the-support-for-classname-andclassname-in-the-current-browsers for more detail.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use multiple class names (a perfectly normal thing to do), but are only allowed one class attribute on your HTML element.

Do this instead:

```
<a href="#" class="paren defaul">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from RedFilters' answer you could of course extend your class selectors by using the [angular](https://angularjs.org/) ng-class attribute as follows:

```html
<a href="#" class="paren defaul" ng-class="['tea', 'mat', 'thirs']">text</a>
```

The resulting html would then be:

```html
<a href="#" class="paren defaul tea mat thirs">text</a>
```

Might come in useful to get around a tslint "line too long" error :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for two class statements, simply:

```
<a href="#" class="paren defaul">text</a>
```

Now, in order to handle this in CSS you need to do this:

```
.paren.default{
}
```

...Whithout spaces between the two class selectors. 
Cheers!