# What's the support for .className.andClassName in the current browsers?

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

*Confusing title?* **Sure!**

In CSS, you can specify:

```
.button.blue {
    ...
}
```

Which will target elements that have ***both*** class names.

***Does anyone know what the browser support is?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen chaining of modifiers fail. I think you're good to go in all browsers still in use today, if not all browsers that ever implemented CSS.

**EDIT**: Nope. Just watched IE6 choke on it. Plugged [this example](http://jsbin.com/iboxu/2/edit) into Adobe Browserlab, and both the class attributes `hello world` and `world` respond to the `.hello.world` selectors.

Booooo, IE6. IE7 is good to go on that point, though.

Here's a [blog post](http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2005/05/16/multiple-class-selectors-in-internet-explorer/) describing the issue (IE just reads the last class, it would seem), and offering the following stupid but necessary fix if IE6 is required: `<p class="one two one-two">`

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski: once I actually tested, nope. IE6 fail :(

Comment: That's what I was afraid of @Matchu :)